# MySQL - Fix multiple records

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT cf.FK_collection, c.collectionName,
  uf.FK_userMe, uf.FK_userYou,
  u.userId, u.username
FROM userFollows as uf
INNER JOIN collectionFollows as cf ON uf.FK_userMe = cf.FK_user
INNER JOIN collections as c ON cf.FK_collection = c.collectionId
INNER JOIN users as u ON uf.FK_userYou = u.userId
WHERE uf.FK_userMe = 2
```

Hey guys.

I'm trying to make this query, and it of course won't do as I want it to, since it's returning multiple rows which is in some way what I want, and yet it's not. Let me try to explain:

I trying to get both collectionFollows and userFollows, for showing a users activity on the site. But when doing this, I will have multiple rows from userFollows even tho a user only follows 1. This occurs because I'm following multiple collectionFollows.

So when I show my result it will return like this:

```
John is following 'webdesign'
John is following 'Lisa'
John is following 'programming'
John is following 'Lisa'
```

I would like to know if I have to make multiple queries or use an subquery? What would be best practice? And how would I write the query then?

Comment: If you know the question has been asked a billion times, you must have found at least a million answers.

Comment: @GolezTrol If I had I wouldn't have written this question. I'm also asking what's best practice which isn't told in other question.

Comment: Allright. Best practice would be to first write a query that works (which yours doesn't), after that you may optimize. I tried to address this in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually combining two quite unrelated queries. I would keep them as separate queries, especially since you report them like that too. You could, if you like, use UNION ALL to combine those queries. This way, you have just a list of names of items you follow, regardless of the type of item it is. If you want, you can specify that too.

```
SELECT 
  cf.user, 
  cf.FK_collection as followItem, 
  c.collectionName as followName,
  'collection' as followType
FROM collectionFollows as cf
INNER JOIN collections as c ON cf.FK_collection = c.collectionId
WHERE cf.user = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  uf.FK_userMe, 
  u.userId, 
  u.username
  'user' as followType
FROM userFollows as uf
INNER JOIN users as u ON uf.FK_userYou = u.userId
WHERE uf.FK_userMe = 2
```

An alternative would be to filter unique values in PHP, but even then your query will fail. Because of the inner joins, you will not get any results if a user only follows other users or only follows collections. You need at least one of both to get any results.
You could change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, but then you would still have to post-process the query to filter doubles and filter out the NULL values.

UNION ALL is fast. It just sticks two query results together without furthes processing. This is different from UNION, which will filter double as well (like DISTINCT). In this case, it is not needed, because I assume a user can only follow a collection or other user once, so these queries will never return duplicate records. If that is indeed the case, UNION ALL will do just fine and will be faster than UNION.

Apart from UNION ALL, two separate queries is fine too.

Comment: This is just perfect. Thanks a lot. A very useful answer! I will now read about UNION all and how it works, so that I'm not just copy-pasting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. They are different! :)